# spsite exist or not

Tags: 2007, development

How can i check if spsite exist or not ?

I have a web address www.portal2010.com/internalportal/employeesites

Now when i try to open web and spsite it opens upper level spsite instead

```
spsite mysite = new site("www.portal2010.com/internalportal/employeesites")
```

How can I check if web exists with address `www.portal2010.com/internalportal/employeesites` or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check the SPWeb object of the subsite to check whether it exists,

```
using(SPSite mysite = new SPSite ("www.portal2010.com/internalportal/employeesites"))
    {
     using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("/internalportal/employeesites"))
      {
        if(web.Exists)
        {
          //Web Exist
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: problem is that, site collection address is www.portal2010.com and "/internalportal/employeesites" doesn't exists so it opens root web instead and donot throw any error as well, i am not knowing child web name as its dynamix

Comment: This actually works, have you tried to execute OpenWeb method with url parameter, not a plain OpenWeb()? It does not throw exception, but web.Exists returns false in case of non-existing site

Comment: it's opening wrong web (root web instead), how can i use web.exists ??

Answer (score 1):

Considering your sitecollection address is "www.portal2010.com/internalportal/employeesites".
then below code won't give error as `OpenWeb()` opens web object associated with the site collection

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("www.portal2010.com/internalportal/employeesites"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {

    }                
}
```

However, if say you want to go into a subsite that may or may not exist at www.portal2010.com/internalportal/employeesites/subsite, you can write following code to check if web exists or not

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("www.portal2010.com/internalportal/employeesites"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("subsite"))
    {
        if (web.Exists)
        {
        }
    }                
}
```

Also, you can't open a site collection which doesn't exist. Following code will throw error:
while trying to create `SPSite` object

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("www.portal2010.com/internalportal/wrongSiteCollection"))
{
    if (site.OpenWeb().Exists)
    {

    }                          
}
```

Comment: problem is that, site collection address is www.portal2010.com and "/internalportal/employeesites" doesn't exists so it opens root web instead and donot throw any error as well, i am not knowing child web name as its dynamix

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool ChildWebExists(SPWeb parentWeb, string childWeb)
{     
   using (SPweb childWebexists = parentWeb.Webs[childWeb]) 
   {         
       return childWebexists.Exists;     
   } 
}
```

it returns a bool value

string childWeb == Gets the web site object witht the specified site-relative url from the collection so it would be the string site name, you can change it to a guid or id instead of string!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.webs.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.exists.aspx

**EDIT**

```
private static bool isWebExists(SPSite spSite, string webRelativeUrl) 
{     
    bool returnVal = false;      
    using (SPWeb currentWeb = spSite.OpenWeb(webRelativeUrl))     
    {     
      try         
      {       
        //Try to access the site property. If it doesn't throw an error, means site already exists.               
         string siteTitle = currentWeb.Title;               
         returnVal = true;           
      }           
      catch         
      {               
        //Do nothing     
      }   
    }      
    return returnVal;
 }
```

if it doesnt exist it will throw an error and as bool is set to false will return false!

http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/code-snippet-how-to-check-if-sharepoint-site-collection-or-sub-site-exists/

Comment: problem is that, site collection address is www.portal2010.com and "/internalportal/employeesites" doesn't exists so it opens root web instead and donot throw any error as well, i am not knowing child web name as its dynamix

Comment: your right, as its dynamic that would be an issue: check out my ammended answer!

Comment: You can just return currentWeb.Exists property instead of trying to access Title property. Generating unnecessary exceptions in code is not a good practice